# Run Windows PhotoViewer on image file with spaces in its path

Tags: visual-c++, command-line, process, createprocess, rundll32

I have a problem with running PhotoViewer on image file with spaces in its path.

I'm using C++ function CreateProcess, supplying a command line as its argument. The command line template for that is:

```
"rundll32 <path to PhotoViewer.dll> ImageView_Fullscreen <path to image> "
e.g.
"rundll32 \"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\" ImageView_Fullscreen Z:\\Documents\\Projects\\ScreenCapture1\\ScreenCapture\\ScreenCapture\\sample.bmp"
```

The problem here is the fact that  must be without double quotes and  cannot contain spaces.

My code is more or less like this

```
_tcscpy_s( str, 200, _T("rundll32 \"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\" ImageView_Fullscreen Z:\\Documents\\Projects\\ScreenCapture1\\ScreenCapture\\ScreenCapture\\sample.bmp") );
CreateProcess( NULL,            // No module name (use command line). 
        str,            // Command line. 
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable. 
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable. 
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE. 
        0,              // No creation flags. 
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block. 
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory. 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
        &pi );          // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.

HANDLE hProcess = pi.hProcess;
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

Now I want to run PhotoViewer on an image file with spaces on its path, for example

```
C:\the folder\has spaces\the image file.bmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the old windows style paths if there is spaces in them with a tilde.

For example,

```
c:\thefol~1\hasspa~1\theima~1.bmp
```

Comment: @poolie: Use GetShortPathName (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989.aspx). But a short style path name is not always available, it can be disabled by the system admin.